# One way of breaking out of a loop is working and the other way is not working

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop

This piece of code does not work

```
    rsp = input("Please enter a command: ").strip()

    while rsp.lower() != "e" or rsp.lower() != "b":
        print("Invalid response, please try again!\n")
        rsp = input("Please enter a command: ").strip()
```

But this one does

```
    while True:
        rsp = input("Please enter a command: ").strip()

        if rsp.lower() == "e" or rsp.lower() == "b":
            break

        print("Invalid response, please try again.\n")
```

Can someone explain why the first code does not work. When I enter "e" or "b" I'm still stuck in the while loop.

Comment: Well think about the logic of your Boolean condition :) You want `and` instead of `or`. [To put it another way, the inverse of an `and` statement is an `or` between each statement's negation. Look up De Morgan's laws if you're interested ]

Comment: Related reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws. Exercise: What is the opposite of `a or b`? What is the opposite of `not a or not b`?

Answer (score 2):

No matter what you enter it will be either not a "e" or not a "b", so your while statement is always true.

Try rsp.lower() != "e" and rsp.lower() != "b" instead.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 conditions are not identical:

```
rsp.lower() != "e" or rsp.lower() != "b":
```

is not the same as

```
rsp.lower() == "e" or rsp.lower() == "b":
```

---

You could make it clearer this way:

```
rsp.lower() in ("e", "b"):
```

which also has the added benefit of only using one call to `.lower()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is within the logic of the `while` loop:

```
while rsp.lower() != "e" or rsp.lower() != "b"
```

Because of the `or` operator, no matter what character is typed for `rsp.lower()` it will not satisfy *both* being "e" and being "b" simultaneously.

That is,

`if rsp.lower() == "e"`: then it doesn't satisfy `rsp.lower() == "b"`

likewise:

`if rsp.lower() == "b"`: then it doesn't satisfy `rsp.lower() == "e"`

What you would want to use is the `and` operator. This will indicate whether the character is neither "b" or "e".:

```
while rsp.lower() != "e" and rsp.lower() != "b":
```